# How to position a p:dialog outside of the browser or iframe window

Tags: html, jsf-2, primefaces

In my application, I render one or more **iframe** elements in the main page, each of which displays the summary of a data record.   What I want to do is to allow the user to click somewhere in that display and pop up a **p:dialog** box that displays more data and input controls.

The problem is that the dialog only shows in the confines of the **iframe**.  Is there a way to allow it to plot outside the border of the iframe rectangle or the browser window?

If not, is there some other JSF component that can do this?

I already posted this question on the primefaces forum, but I think they are too busy to respond.

Comment: yours tags are completely misleading - this is a html/css question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible. All modern browsers prevent any visual elements from leaving the confines of the browser's rendering area. This is to prevent a web page spoofing bona-fide operating system windows, among other things. An iframe is also considered a separate "browser" for the purposes of this limitation.

Additionally, this is a pure html/css/browser limitation. The tools (jsf/asp.net/php/etc) used do not come into it.

Some more info (from IE6/sp2+):

**About Window Restrictions**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537638(v=vs.85).aspx

These constraints are equally applicable to all modern browsers (not that IE6 is modern, but that's kind of my point.)

Comment: A popup is an entirely new browser window, and is recognizable as such. Modern browsers force the address bar to remain at the top of the "popup" window to remind people of this fact.

Comment: OK i think you answered my question then -- I need to pop up a new browser window when the user clicks.  A javascript implemented dialog box like **p:dialog** won't work.    I checked on your answer thanks.